# jQuery and JavaScript onmouseover compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an eBay listing and it work's correctly on eBay.

But I have an issue. The listing's are listed via 3rd party software and that software has their own JS for changing the images. And it doesn't work with my scripts. I use jQuery.

Can anyone advice a simple method to swap the image src on click event?

For example: Leave as it is, but overwrite the JS. Now it is set up to listen for mouse hover. Can I write a new script so when clicked it would swap the images?

Here is the link to the listing: [Listing template here](http://www.ebay.es/itm/LOEWE-AGUA-DE-LOEWE-EAU-DE-TOILETTE-150-ML-SPRAY-/281157328240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change src attribute of an image :

```
$('#myImage').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'myNewImage.jpg');
});
```

To stop listening to the mouseover event :

```
$('#myTargetWhichHasAnEventAttached').off('mouseover');
```

Edit to answer the comment :

```
$('.image_small_js').off('mouseover'); // supposed that the mouseover event is attached on .image_small_js

$('.image_small_js').click(function(){
    $('#bigpicture').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).hide().show(); // .hide().show() makes the change effect more smoothy... can be used with timers
});
```

Comment: I don't get how it will work for me? 

I need to click on the image with `class="image_small_js"` then take the url for that image and put in the src of the images with `id="bigpicture"`

Comment: yes, it works! Thank you. But I saw another problem. The SRC isn't the one I need. I'm sorry! As you can see the src of thumbnails is: [thumbnail](http://x.cloudsdata.net/9j/images/products/thumbnails/52318adcc396c_agua-de-loewe.jpg) and the main image is [Large image](http://x.cloudsdata.net/9j/images/products/large/52318adcc396c_agua-de-loewe.jpg) as you can see the folder changes from `thumbnails` to `large` is it posible to affect this?

Comment: ok, did it. Added this to the code you wrote! `.replace('thumbnails', 'large')`